# How to get value from a dropdown menu and display it in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, menu

I'm using react and have a dropdown menu with numbers 1-5. I want to select the value of the one clicked and display it in the dropdown menu but I'm not able to show the value.

Is it possible to solve it without using select or similar?

```
handleToggle = (clicked) => {
    this.setState(() => ({
      toggle: !this.state.toggle,
    }));
  };

  handleAmount = (e) => {
    this.setState(() => ({
      amount: e.target.value,
      toggle: !this.state.toggle,
    }));
  };

<section
          value={this.state.amount}
          onClick={this.handleAmount}
        >
          <section
            className="arrow-down"
            onClick={this.handleToggle}
          ></section>
          <section>
            <p
              value="1"
              className={`${this.state.toggleHide ? "hide" : ""}`}
            >
              1 WHALE
            </p>
            <p
              value="2"
              className={`${this.state.toggleHide ? "hide" : ""}`}
            >
              2 WHALES
            </p>
</section>
</section>
```

Comment: This is a fragment of a component, is there a reason you can't provide your entire component?

Comment: No specific reason, just not necessary I think. But I decided to fix it with react-select instead